# How to set flashdevelop with AIR 2.6

Tags: air, flashdevelop

I would like to set my FlashDevelop to use the new AIR 2.6 SDK. I [saw this thread on the FD forum](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=8115) but I couldn't get a working walkthrough.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

hey, you can try this tutorial I've written: http://jvcaalim.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-tos-android-development-using.html, if you have any questions feel free to post them on the blog, hope it helps!